# Navigation drawer is not opening from APPBar widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, drawer, appbar

I have an appbar which is used in more than one screen. I have a navigation drawer in the home screen. As the appbar is used in multiple places, i created as a separate widget. But I am not able to access navigation drawer. So I included appbar code in all the screens I needed. Then it works fine. But it will be code duplicate. Is there any fix for this in Flutter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not done so yet , you can make a separate class for drawer

```
getAppDrawer(){
  return Drawer(
    //your code
  );
}
```

and then you can call this in your others screen

```
drawer : getAppDrawer(),
```

you can also do this for the appbar

[Take a look at the examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53411890/how-can-i-have-my-appbar-in-a-separate-file-in-flutter-while-still-having-the-wi)

[and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659805/persisting-appbar-drawer-across-all-pages-flutter)